# Javascript non human readable variable / function declaration

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and need help from community.

Here's a piece of javascript that has some sort of hex value variable declaration or function declaration
I need to understand what is the meaning of _0xbf56x2b and others like this if there is any meaning to them.
On the first appearance it does look like hex but I didn't get any meaning even after converting them to ASCII.

This is a really huge javascript file and below is a sample section from that file. This huge javascript file is filled with mostly these (for example _0xbf56x2b) sort of variable or functions declaration, if anyone would be able to guide me to what is the meaning or how should I decode this it will be very helpful.

'''

```
function timeCheck() {
    var **_0xbf56x2b** = $(Main_Arr[8])[Main_Arr[7]]();    
    var **_0xbf56x2c** = new Date(_0xbf56x2b);    
    var **_0xbf56x2d** = new Date();    
    var **_0xbf56x2e** = (_0xbf56x2d[Main_Arr[9]]() + 1) + Main_Arr[10] + _0xbf56x2d[Main_Arr[11]]() +  
    Main_Arr[10] + **_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[12]]() + Main_Arr[13];    
    if (**_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[14]]() > 12) {
**_0xbf56x2e** = **_0xbf56x2e** + (**_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[14]]() - 12);    
    } else {    
        **_0xbf56x2e** = **_0xbf56x2e** + **_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[14]]();    
    };    
    if (**_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[15]]() < 10) {    
        **_0xbf56x2e** = **_0xbf56x2e** + Main_Arr[16] + **_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[15]]();    
    } else {    
        **_0xbf56x2e** = **_0xbf56x2e** + Main_Arr[17] + **_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[15]]();    
    };    
    if (**_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[18]]() < 10) {    
        **_0xbf56x2e** = **_0xbf56x2e** + Main_Arr[16] + **_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[18]]();    
    } else {    
        **_0xbf56x2e** = **_0xbf56x2e** + Main_Arr[17] + **_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[18]]();    
    };    
    timedifference = (**_0xbf56x2d**[Main_Arr[19]]() - **_0xbf56x2c**[Main_Arr[19]]()) / 60000;    
    if (timedifference < 5) {    
        alert(Main_Arr[20] + **_0xbf56x2e** + Main_Arr[21]);    
    };    
};
```

'''

Comment: `var **_0xbf56x2b**` throws a syntax error? Did you add the `**` in the example?

Comment: It’s simply obfuscated code, with meaningful variable names replaced with nonsense for the purpose of obscuring the logic.

Comment: It should not be that problematic. Just take your IDE or any text editor and replace each variable across the code with a replacement-name. E.g. `**_0xbf56x2b**` = `variable1`and so forth. Then you gain a more readable code which runs. In the next steps you try to understand, with the help of console.log(), which variable does what and rename them.

Comment: yes @evolution box,  ** is stack overflow's way of making the text go bold

Comment: @mrsorrted not inside a code block though

Comment: @lynx 242, I have tried doing that but there are so many of these that its difficult to convert them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah, please ignore ** prefix and suffix from the variables. For example if variable is appearing **_0xbf56x2b**, you must read it as _0xbf56x2b only.

Comment: Give me 15min and I'll get back to you. ;)

Comment: @charlietfl The algorithm is pretty certainly “generate random code”.

Comment: https://jsnice.org/ is nice for deobfuscation.

Comment: @LoganDevine thank you for the suggestion, but jsnice.org is appearing dead site.

Comment: @mrsorrted: It's HTTP only. StackOverflow makes all links https

Comment: @LoganDevine Thanks, it worked with HTTP. It did pretty decent job, but I am still left with couple thousand _0xbf56x2b such variables. I am happy with at least some progress.

Comment: @mrsorrted: Try their Interactive Rename feature, it could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, referring to my experience with "Date- and Time-Computing" this is what your unobfuscated code is supposed to look like.

`_0xbf56x2d` = `currentDate`

`_0xbf56x2c` = `selectedDate`

`_0xbf56x2b` = `timestamp`

`_0xbf56x2e` = `currentDateAsString`

```
function timeCheck() {
    var timestamp = "01.01.1970 00:00:00"; // I don't know the source of this timestamp. Must be some global array.    
    var selectedDate = new Date(timestamp);    
    var currentDate = new Date();    
    
    
    var currentDateAsString = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "." + currentDate.getDate() + "." + currentDate.getYear() + " ";    
    
    
    if (currentDate.getHours() > 12) {
        currentDateAsString = currentDateAsString + (currentDate.getHours() - 12);    
    } else {    
        currentDateAsString = currentDateAsString + currentDate.getHours();    
    };    
    if (currentDate.getMinutes() < 10) {    
        currentDateAsString = currentDateAsString + ":0" + currentDate.getMinutes();    
    } else {    
        currentDateAsString = currentDateAsString + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes();    
    };    
    if (currentDate.getSeconds() < 10) {    
        currentDateAsString = currentDateAsString + ":0" + currentDate.getSeconds();    
    } else {    
        currentDateAsString = currentDateAsString + ":" + currentDate.getSeconds();    
    };    
    
    timedifference = (currentDate.getMilliseconds() - selectedDate.getMilliseconds()) / 60000;    
    if (timedifference < 5) {    
        alert(currentDateAsString);    
    };    
};
```

So now it should be clear what it does.

First it takes a timestamp out of an array or a global variable and generates a Date with it.
Then it concatenates a human readable representation of the current timestamp.
Finally it compares the timestamp out of the unknown source against now. If the differences is less than 5 millis, it alerts the human readable timestamp.

Comment: thank you so much for the efforts, but I have a javascript code thats 4k lines and is filled with lots of such variables, and the above snippet is one sample function from that huge javascript code. I need a fix to make sense of that obfuscated code having 4k lines approximately.

Comment: Well, honestly speaking: Without a tool that specializes on this, you won't succeed. As you can see in my example there is a lot of background knowledge necessary in order to recognize patterns.

Comment: I too agree ! I shall keep on searching for the tool required for this task. Thanks again for your generous help.